# Invalid OAuth Token on Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Iam currently trying to figure out on how to post to the feed of a Facebook page via API.

I get following response when trying to call the API with:
`https://graph.facebook.com/<page_ID>/feed?message=RGllcyBpc3QgZWluIFRlc3Q=&published=true&access_token=<page_access_token>`

```json
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Invalid OAuth 2.0 Access Token",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 190,
    "error_subcode": 2069032,
    "is_transient": false,
    "error_user_title": "Zugriffsschlüssel des Nutzers wird nicht unterstützt",
    "error_user_msg": "Für diesen Aufruf ist ein Seiten-Zugriffsschlüssel für die neue Seitenversion erforderlich.",
    "fbtrace_id": "AbIsj2fXolu7QnHTT9N5mkf
"
  }
}
```

On the first look it looks like there is a problem with my `access_key`, but when I debug it it says that everything should be right.

The access_key has following permissions: pages_show_list, business_management, pages_read_engagement, pages_manage_metadata, pages_read_user_content, pages_manage_posts, pages_manage_engagement. The type is "Page" and it has the page_id where I am trying to post the message.

Has anyone a idea on how to post to a page?

Comment: The German parts of the error message suggest that your page has already been converted to the "New Page Experience." If you are using an "old" access token here, I'd try and generate a new one first. And try and follow this guide, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages-api/getting-started

Comment: @CBroe i actually just figured it out. So i was using the Graph API Explorer and if you type the access_token as payload in the post request it actually gets overwritten with the acces_token in the right field. But thank you for your fast response!